# How to format numbers to be stored as text in excel?

Tags: excel

In excel I have many cells of number in a column formatted as text. I want to convert them into a formatting "number stored as text". I can do it for a single cell at a time by putting an apostrophe (') before the number and pressing enter. My problem is how to achieve this type of formatting for rest of the cell quickly. I have tried to create a new column as ="'"&A2 and copy, but it does not work.

In the attached figure I have converted cell A2 as number formatted as text by putting an ' before it and want to do the same for rest of the cell quickly.[image: number formatted as text with an apostrophe]

Comment: You can just select the entire column and change cell formatting from General to Text

Comment: I do not just want to convert number into text or text into numbers. I want to convert all numbers or text into "numbers stored as text with an apostrophe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it may not be the fastest solution, just select the cells you want to be text and set the formatting to text => hit <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

In the "Immediate" window run:

```
for each x in selection.cells: x.value = format(x.text,"'@"): next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a helper column.
You'll need to know what the numberformat was before you formatted the column as text.  Then just use that same format in this formula:

```
=TEXT(A1,"number_format")
```

eg:

```
=TEXT(A1,"General")
```

or

```
=TEXT(A1,"0")
```

> Fill down as far as necessary.

Next, select the cells in the column with the formula and `Edit-Copy`; `Edit-Paste Special Values`  This will replace the formula with the text result.